# Android jsoup select titles one by one

Tags: android, jsoup

I am new to android. I want to get all the headline one by one using jsoup.

If  have 10 headline I want it all 
My code is

```
Elements localElements1 = localDocument.select("ul[id=newslist] img[alt]")
```

It selects 1 headline. But I need all from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
Elements elems = localDocument.select("ul#newslist img[alt]");
```

`elems` in this code is a list of all `img` elements which have attribute `alt`. To iterate over this list you can do like this:

```
for(Element img : elems){
    System.out.println(img.attr("alt"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need only type of item and its id (or class), you don't need other element (img).
Write the code like this,

```
Elements localElements1 = localDocument.select("ul#newslist");
```

Select items by img attributes under ul,

```
Elements localElements1 = localDocument.select(".ul#newslist > img[alt]");
```

or

```
Elements localElements1 = localDocument.select(".ul#newslist img[alt]");
```

Comment: <ul id="newslist">
<img src="http://cinema.dinakaran.com/Karan_img/gallery/Kollywood-news-8151.jpg" alt="சேதுபதி " title="sethubathy" /></a>
<img src="http://cinema.dinakaran.com/Karan_img/gallery/Kollywood-news-8150.jpg" alt="மிருதன்" title="Mirudhan" /></a>                      from this 2 img src I nedd 2 titles from alt attribute